# How to subscribe mosquitto broker raspberry pi b3+ topics from web through port forwarding

Tags: mqtt

My router's static IP is set for Raspberry Pi.

```
mosquitto_sub -t he -u "hello" -p "world"
```

Error:

```
Invalid port given: 0
he --------topic name
```

The above error is occurring - please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome To Stackoverflow,!!  Please read [how to ask question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

From the mosquitto_sub [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) page:

> **-p, --port**
>
> Connect to the port specified. If not given, the default of 1883 for plain MQTT or 8883 for MQTT over TLS will be used.
>
> **-P, --pw**
>
> Provide a password to be used for authenticating with the broker. Using this argument without also specifying a username is invalid. See
>   also the --username option.